# Problem converting to consistent UTM when straddling zones

Tags: python, utm

I need to get a set of coordinates in meters, given lat/long positions using the utm module in python.  If the positions straddle different zones, the maps become incorrect.  After checking a number of discussions I haven't yet found a direct solution.

```py
lat_points = [42.827990, 42.849890, 42.824294]
long_points = [95.9, 95.903, 96.01]
xy_meters = [utm.from_latlon(lat,long) for (lat, long) in zip(lat_points,long_points)]
for row in xy_meters:
    print(row)
```

The result shows a large gap when the zone crosses over:

```
(737040.3354880156, 4745793.498913411, 46, 'T')
(737201.7056600684, 4748234.076861802, 46, 'T')
(255588.1599583785, 4745640.325228949, 47, 'T')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think this code works as intended (switching packages):

```py
from pyproj import Proj
myProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=46T, +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
for lat, long in zip(lat_points,long_points):
    print(myProj(long, lat))
```

Gives the desired:

```
(737040.3354579052, 4745793.4987486005)
(737201.7056297899, 4748234.076696485)
(746046.8172912733, 4745698.570316798)
```